# .NET Standard 2.0 NuGet Package Generation

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard

I am working with my .NET class library project that targets Multiple .NET frameworks and now after having downloaded the **.NET Core 2.0 SDK** in my Windows 10 machine I am trying to target `.NET Standard 2.0` as well.

`<TargetFrameworks>net45;net46;netstandard1.0;netstandard1.3;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>`

The problem is that when the **NuGet** package generated by *Visual Studio (2017)* after compilation is opened via **NuGet Package Explorer** it shows that for `.NET Standard 2.0` there are no dependencies.

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

Shouldn't it be having **NETStandard.Library 2.0.0** as a dependency?

If so is it necessary (at-least till an update is released for VS) that a dependency is explicitly specified in the NuGet package for **NETStandard.Library 2.0.0**?

To be certain that it wasn't an isolated case with my project I created another project and added Newtonsoft.Json as a dependency. The result was still the same.

[image: Screenshot3]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default `NETStandard.Library` version is still `1.6.1` when publishing for .NET Standard versions lower than 2.0. While the `2.0.0` version is technically the same (it has the same list of dependencies for the older .NET Standard versions), you risk creating downgrade warnings for consuming projects that reference version `1.6.1`.

For .NET Standard versions 2.0 and higher, no dependency on `NETStandard.Library` is needed so your library will show "No Dependencies" as long as you don't add any additional NuGet packages.

Comment: +1 for the clarification but I am still unsure about the last part that it will show `No Dependencies` as long as I don't add any additional *NuGet* package reference. As you can see in the screenshot above, even after I added *Newtonsoft.Json* as a dependency the result was still the same.

Comment: @AmatuerDev yes, and that is what Martin was saying. NETStandard.Library no longer shows up as a dependencies, if you have other dependencies like Newtonsoft.Json it will show up, but NetStandard.Library will still not show up.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Well that explains it. I guess I read the last part wrong. Marking this as an answer. Thanks mate.